# How to set autoscaling on Kubernetes elastic search based on storage uses

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

How to set autoscaling on Kubernetes elastic search based on storage uses

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/xpack-autoscaling.html